# Spring MVC, Spring Security: Unable to load login template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

When to access any route, I get redirected to my login page, including accessing my login page, which is expected. Now the problem is the login page does not even load. I have configured the controller method, hander, template configuration, and security configuration necessary to make this work, but all I get is the error below:

http://localhost:8080/login?errorMessage=Login+to+use+the+app

[image]

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "signup";
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public String createUser(User user) {
        // only create user if it does not exist
        if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) == null) {
            user.setRoles(new String[] {"ROLE_USER"});
            userService.save(user);
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
        else {
            return "redirect:/signup";
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/profile")
    public String currentUserProfile(Model model) {
        User currentUser = (User) model.asMap().get("currentUser");
        model.addAttribute("user", currentUser);
        model.addAttribute("authorized", true);
        return "profile";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String userProfile(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        User queriedUser = userService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", queriedUser);

        User currentUser = (User) model.asMap().get("currentUser");
        if (currentUser != null && currentUser.isAdmin()) {
            model.addAttribute("authorized", true);
        }

        return "profile";
    }
}
```

**UserHandler.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.valencra.recipes.web.controller")
public class UserHandler {
    public static final String USERNAME_NOT_FOUND_ERR_MSG = "Unable to find username";
    public static final String ACCESS_DENIED_ERR_MSG = "Login to use the app";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("authenticatedUser")
    public User addAuthenticatedUser() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
            if (user != null) {
                return user;
            }
            else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(USERNAME_NOT_FOUND_ERR_MSG);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(ACCESS_DENIED_ERR_MSG);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public String redirectIfUserNotAuthenticated(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("errorMessage", ACCESS_DENIED_ERR_MSG);
    return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class)
    public String redirectIfUserNotFound(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("errorMessage", USERNAME_NOT_FOUND_ERR_MSG);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

**TemplateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private RecipesAppUserDetailsService recipesAppUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(recipesAppUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .permitAll()
          .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
          .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
          .and()
          .logout()
          .permitAll()
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
          .and()
          .csrf().disable();

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
    }

    public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
        return (request, response, exception) ->       
        response.sendRedirect("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
            @Override
            public String getExtensionId() {
                return "security";
            }

             @Override
             public Object getRootObject() {
                 Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# Package where our entities (models) are located
recipes.entity.package = com.valencra.recipes.model

# Details for our datasource
recipes.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
recipes.db.url = jdbc:h2:mem:recipes

# Hibernate properties
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop

spring.data.rest.basePath=/api/v1
```

**resources directory**

[image]

**EDIT**: See @lgaleazzi's answer, and the comments that follow. Essentially, removing the UserHandler class fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the stack trace say?

Looking at your UserHandler, you handle a null authenticated object, and a user you can find. You don't deal with what happens with an anonymous user. I think that's the issue.

If nobody is authenticated, you'll get an authentication object with an anonymous user. You can check that with the method isAuthenticated(). But you don't actually have to write this code, Spring Boot handles all this pretty well with its default configuration.

Comment: Hi lgaleazzi so there are no errors in the stack trace, just a bunch of hibernate console outputs. When I run the debugger, I see that it returns an anonymous user, and it does throw the username not found exception, which gets handled by a redirect to the login page, which I think is okay. However, what I don’t understand is why the login page does not get rendered at all.

Comment: Because you have an exception handler that redirects to the login page when the UserNotFoundException is thrown. So you load the login page, it looks for the user, doesn't find it, throws the exception, redirects to login. And again, and again. Which is why you get the "too many redirects" error from your browser.

Comment: Your UserHandler does not allow for anonymous access at all. And nobody will ever be able to access the login page and authenticate if you don't allow for anonymous access. You should remove that class and let the configuration in your SecurityConfig class take care of that for you.

Comment: Ah that fixes it! Thanks @lgaleazzi!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following method to `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // configuring here URLs for which security filters
    // will be disabled (this is equivalent to using
    // security="none")
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login");
}
```

There you can specify URLs in your application for which authentication should not be applied (also useful for static resources).

In your case, `/login` is not excluded from authentication scope, so it causes one more redirection to `/login`, and you get a vicious circle.

Comment: Hi Roman so when I add that method, I get a login pop-up, instead of my custom login page, even when I try to access the "/login" route.

Comment: And now it's back to just displaying: http://localhost:8080/login?errorMessage=Login+to+use+the+app This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Thanks, Roman, I confirm that adding the login URL to the permit matcher is required.
In my case ".antMatchers("*.css", "*.js","/pages/login/").permitAll()"